# How can you resolve module imports in a Typescript transformer

Tags: typescript, import, module, transformer-model

I'm writing a Typescript transformer that needs to follow import declarations to understand what the import is. I'm having some trouble getting it working though.

Using `ts-loader` with the option `transpileOnly: true` ends up having the `resolvedModules` property on the `SourceFile` be undefined. If I set `transpileOnly: false` it is defined - however that brings other issues.

Is there any *official* way of resolving/visiting module imports? If you have any best practices or other handy hints for writing transformers I'm all ears as well :).

Cheers

Comment: Is this maybe related to my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718877/typescript-transformer-follow-module-imports