# Resolve types from imported modules inside a typescript transformer when in transpileOnly mode with ts-loader

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to tell typescript to load the unresolved modules when in transpileMode inside a transformer function? The question behind question is I want to get access to the imported types and enumerate the interface properties and their subtypes into a json object.

Setting `transpileOnly: false` in ts-loader, brings other hosts of error and makes compiling 10X slower, so having this work with `transpileOnly: true` is a requirement.

This question is different from: [TypeScript Transformer - Follow Module Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718877/typescript-transformer-follow-module-imports), since `typeChecker.getAliasedSymbol(argumentSymbol)` doesn't work with `transpileOnly: true`

```js
// @ts-check

/**
 * whether node is `typeAsJsonSchema<T>()` CallExpression
 * @param {ts.Node} node
 * @returns {node is ts.CallExpression}
 */
function isTypeAsJsonSchemaCallExpression(node) {
  if (ts.isCallExpression(node) && ts.isIdentifier(node.expression)) {
    const fnName = node.expression.text;
    const isTypeAsJsonSchemaFn = fnName === `typeAsJsonSchema`;
    const hasTypeArg = node.typeArguments && node.typeArguments.length === 1;
    return isTypeAsJsonSchemaFn && hasTypeArg;
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * The main transformer function that transforms the AST before emit
 * @param {ts.Program} program
 * @returns {ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile>}
 */
function attrsSchemaTransformer(program) {
  const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
  return (context) => {
    return (sourceFile) => {
      /** @type {ts.Visitor} */
      const visit = (node) => {
        if (isTypeAsJsonSchemaCallExpression(node)) {
          const type = typeChecker.getTypeFromTypeNode(node.typeArguments[0]);
          const typeProps = typeChecker.getPropertiesOfType(type);
          console.log(type);

          const diags = ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program, sourceFile);
          console.log(diags.map((d) => `${d.code}: ${d.messageText}`));
        }

        return ts.visitEachChild(node, (child) => visit(child), context);
      };
      return ts.visitNode(sourceFile, visit);
    };
  };
}
```

This returns diagnostic errors such as

```
  "2307: Cannot find module './util/type-transforms'.",
  "2307: Cannot find module './foo/types'.",
```

the source file is

```js
import {typeAsJsonSchema} from './util/type-transforms';
import type {FooBarType} from 'foo/types';

console.log(typeAsJsonSchema<FooBarType>());
```

Getting acccess to the `FooBarType`returns `Any` and `Unknown` flags with `transpileOnly: true`. With `transpileOnly: false`, I can enumerate the interface properties with `const typeProps = typeChecker.getPropertiesOfType(type);` and get the subtypes.

I tried digging into typescript compiler internals on how to resolve module types. There is `ts.resolveModuleName` function but I'm not sure how to give it access to compiler host from `program`.

The issue I am blocked is getting typescript to **resolve the imports and link to the imported types**, before calling `typeChecker.getTypeFromTypeNode(node.typeArguments[0]);`

Comment: Regarding `ts.resolveModuleName` and compiler host. Does it work if you just create a new compiler host and pass it compiler options from program?

`ts.createCompilerHost(program.getCompilerOptions())`